# iptables with sticky forwarding/routing

Tags: linux, iptables, firewall, routing, nat

My iptables is sticking. I have a DNS server behind IPTables and down a NAT'ed OpenVPN pipe. Using tcpdump I see DNS packets hit the outside router but it takes 4 or 5 DNS query attempts before the DNS request actually travels down the pipe to hit the dns server.
Server is freshly updated, issue still persist.
What could be causing this 'sticky routing' and how do I get rid of it?

iptables-save:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Wed Oct 15 18:53:53 2014
*security
:INPUT ACCEPT [6661499:1780706800]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [1395363:1087119696]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [9054598:4470085569]
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Oct 15 18:53:53 2014
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Wed Oct 15 18:53:53 2014
*raw
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [8279921:2932266784]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [9054600:4470085953]
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Oct 15 18:53:53 2014
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Wed Oct 15 18:53:53 2014
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [608923:62822718]
:INPUT ACCEPT [21598:1030929]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [1936482:102286294]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [1846412:66372854]
-A PREROUTING -d 198.74.49.126/32 -i eth0 -p tcp -m multiport --dports 21,25,80,10000 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.8.0.14
-A PREROUTING -d 198.74.49.126/32 -i eth0 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.8.0.22
-A PREROUTING -d 198.74.49.126/32 -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.8.0.22
-A PREROUTING -d 198.74.49.126/32 -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8080 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.8.0.26
-A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source 198.74.49.126
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Oct 15 18:53:53 2014
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Wed Oct 15 18:53:53 2014
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [8279921:2932266784]
:INPUT ACCEPT [6884197:1845120939]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [1395724:1087145845]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [9054603:4470086441]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [10545150:5593566425]
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Oct 15 18:53:53 2014
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Wed Oct 15 18:53:53 2014
*filter
:INPUT DROP [216663:64020937]
:FORWARD DROP [355:25909]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [9054603:4470086441]
:PRELUDE - [0:0]
-A INPUT -j PRELUDE
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 2222 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 218.1.21.162/32 -m comment --comment "ignore this spammer(?)" -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,21,25,53,8080,10000 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m multiport --dports 53,1194,2222,3333,4444,5555,6666,7777 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -j PRELUDE
-A FORWARD -i tun+ -o tun+ -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i tun+ -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -d 10.8.0.14/32 -i eth0 -o tun+ -p tcp -m multiport --dports 21,25,53,80 -m comment --comment "allow tcp to server" -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -d 10.8.0.22/32 -i eth0 -o tun+ -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -m comment --comment "allow udp to dns server" -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -d 10.8.0.22/32 -i eth0 -o tun+ -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -m comment --comment "allow tcp to dns server" -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -d 10.8.0.26/32 -i eth0 -o tun+ -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8080 -m comment --comment "allow tcp to dns server" -j ACCEPT
-A PRELUDE -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A PRELUDE -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
-A PRELUDE -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A PRELUDE -p icmp -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Oct 15 18:53:53 2014
```

openvpn.conf:

```
local 198.74.50.169
port 1194
;proto tcp
proto udp
;dev tap
dev tun
;dev-node MyTap
ca /usr/share/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/ca.crt
cert /usr/share/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/server.crt
key /usr/share/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/server.key  # This file should be kept secret
dh /usr/share/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/dh1024.pem
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
route 10.8.1.0 255.255.255.0
client-config-dir /etc/openvpn/ccd
push "dhcp-option DNS 66.228.35.79"
push "dhcp-option DNS 10.8.0.22"
;push "dhcp-option WINS 10.8.0.1"
client-to-client
keepalive 10 120
comp-lzo
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
verb 5
;mute 20
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure your trusted ips in named.conf reflect your front end router.